# How do I redirect /search/ to /?s=

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

I have a typical Wordpress site, with a typical Search page set up which uses the typical GET format

```
    <form id="searchform" action="http://example.com" method="get">
        <input id="s" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Again">
    </form>
```

For users' convenience, I'd like to have the following url redirect to the search page:

```
http://example.com/search?search-term
```

Redirect to:

```
http://example.com/search/search-term
```

How do I do this?

I need this to work even if the user enters no search parameter. In other words, if the user enters:

```
http://example.com/search/
```

...the displayed URL should remain

```
http://example.com/search/
```

Not the typical

```
http://example.com/?s=
```

...even though the page is still redirecting to the Wordpress search template.

Hope that made sense.

UPDATE: The closest I've been able to get is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

   # redirect /search/param to /?s=param
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
   RewriteRule ^search/?$ /?s=%1 [R=302,L]  

   #standard wordpress stuff    
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ah, your example (`/search?search-term`) uses a query string, however, your code suggests a slash is desirable instead? `?` or `/`? And, do you really mean a "redirect", or an _internal rewrite_ (again, your description conflicts with your code)? Which URL do you want to see in the address bar?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology. I really don't care if the displayed URL is /search/whatever or /search/?s=whatever. What matters most to me is that the users be able to simply type /search/ and go to the search page. Your solution below is fine, but it doesn't handle the case of no search term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match against the query string (everything after the first `?`) you need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against the QUERY_STRING server variable. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* only matches against the URL-path.

So, try something like the following in .htaccess, *before* any WordPress rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^search/?$ /?s=%1 [R=302,L]
```

If the user requests `/search?[something]` then they are redirected. Where `[something]` is entirely optional.

This is a temporary (302) redirect, change to a permanent (301) when you are sure it's working OK.

---

**UPDATE:** Instead of using the query string to pass the search term (ie. `/search?search-term`, use the URL-path instead (ie. `/search/search-term`). And keep the original URL in the browser (ie. don't externally redirect to `/?s=`) then try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^search(/(.*))? index.php?s=$2 [L]
```

(This replaces *both* the directives above.)

This allows you to specify either `/search`, `/search/` or `/search/search-term` and the URL stays in the browsers address bar.

Comment: That works so long as there is a search parameter. But I also need it to work if the URL is simply /search or /search/ with -no- parameters. How can I add that ability?

Comment: I've updated my answer. This does use a query string ie. `/search?term` (as per your example) or `/search/?term` - you don't need to use a query string if you don't want to. It could be `/search/term`?

Comment: This is great. Your answer is what I asked for. However, I updated my question because I think it looks a LOT better if the rewritten URL is /search/ rather than /?s=1. Can you tell me how to make the RewriteRule generate /search/ when there is no parameter passed?

Comment: I've updated my answer. (The update uses the URL-path eg. `/search/search-term`, rather than the query string.)

Comment: Your updated solution doesn't work for me. Just throws a 404. Perhaps the new line: RewriteRule ^search(/(.*))? index.php?s=$2 [L] conflicts with the standard Wordpress .htaccess statements? (I added what I have to the question.)

Comment: Try temporarily adding the `R` flag to that directive. Does it redirect?

Comment: I added the [R=302,L] and it does 'work' but the URL displayed is example.com/index.php?s=  Is there a way to get the Search template to 'work' but have the displayed URL remain /search/ ? Sorry to pile on, since this is beyond my original question.

Comment: "have the displayed URL remain /search/ ?" - Well, remove the `R` flag (like you had). However, I _think_ WordPress might be kicking in and triggering the 404 when it tries to route the request? I don't use WP so much, but I think WP must route the request based on the REQUEST_URI. The problem here is that we have changed the REQUEST_URI to `/search/search-term` and WP doesn't know about the `/search/search-term` page hence the 404. (I'm guessing.)

Comment: Is there anyway to tell WP not to do anything with the request, ie. don't route it? We are already routing the request by _internally rewriting_ (without the `R` flag) to `/index.php?s=<search-term>`.